# What does :: before array means in C++ explicitly in below code?

Tags: c++, arrays

In the below code I could not understand what does `::` before array `add[i]` means. Can anyone give me a general idea of what does this means in c++ if added before array data structure?(This is general for reference only code)

```
#define FOR(ii,aa,bb) for(int ii=aa;ii<=bb;ii++)

    FOR(i, 1, n) {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        double add = dist(Tx, Ty, x, y);
        all += add * 2;
        suff[i] = pre[i] = dist(Cx, Cy, x, y) - add;
        ::add[i] = dist(Kx, Ky, x, y) - add;
    }
```

Comment: What is that `FOR` macro you seem to be using? If you're going to write real, idiomatic, C++ (instead of basically writing C in C++) you shouldn't use macros like that.

Comment: `::` indicates that `::add` resides in global scope.

Comment: `::` before a symbol indicates the global namespace, so it is referring to a different `add` to the one declared just above.

Comment: Guys, that FOR is just for reference only added define statement now, I don't think it even matters in the reference of this question.....as I wanted general ans didn't wanted to post whole code

Answer (score 1):

It means it is referencing the array `add` defined in the global namespace rather than the local variable `add` defined in the block of code following the FOR macro.

Usually you'd just give the local variable a different name. And most times you wouldn't have a global mutable variable either.

Comment: Understood, Thanks